# Odd Chrome Fonts (Helvetica related)

Tags: google-chrome, fonts

Recently I've been having an issue with fonts in Google Chrome. On certain pages, where Helvetica is used, I get some random glyph type things instead:

[image]

I know this is related to the Helvetica font because it happened when I installed Helvetica and I've had it before. I don't often use Helvetica, but I needed it for something. I've had this before and I've just deleted the font and it's solved the issue.

However, I'm at my wits end this time. I cannot work out why it's happening. I've deleted Helvetica, I've cleaned the registry with CCleaner and emptied the font cache and yet the issue still persists.

Could anyone suggest anything that might fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to find a solution.

Go to:
*User\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\User StyleSheets*

Open "Custom.CSS" and add this (it's usually a blank file):

@font-face { font-family: 'helvetica neue'; src: local('Arial'); }
@font-face { font-family: 'helvetica neue'; font-weight:bold; src: local('Arial');

Then *Save As* with the file type "*All Files*".

This basically tells all CSS in Chrome to use Arial instead of Helvetica and Helvetica Neue.

I had previously tried this method, but just saved it rather than saving as a generic file. For some reason, this fixed it for me.