# Weird Chrome font rendering issue on Ubuntu, numbers only?

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, fonts, facebook

after a fresh re-install of Lubuntu 16.04 (over my old 14.04 Xubuntu install), I'm seeing a strange issue with rendering numbers in Chrome on some sites (attached). Specifically, the numbers appear very small and misplaced, and the font looks unusual. This doesn't appear to happen in Firefox. Facebook is a prime offender, though it's not the only site where I see this and I don't see it on every site.

I've installed the Microsoft TrueType fonts, using the Debian package to get around the bug in the 16.04 package where they fail to download.

Running Lubuntu 16.04 (i.e., Xenial w/ LXDE), and have tried this on Chrome versions 55.0.2883.87 (64-bit) and 56.0.2924.59 beta (64-bit).

[image: Odd glitch 1]
[image: Odd glitch 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the problem is specifically with the font "Palatino," which isn't installed on my computer. It seems to be falling back to something super weird -- not sure how to tell what.

One (hack-y, non-"typographically correct") solution can be found [here](https://superuser.com/questions/684428/odd-chrome-fonts-helvetica-related?rq=1): add a custom user stylesheet (on my machine: `.config/google-chrome/Default/User StyleSheets/Custom.css`) to replace Palatino with Garamond: `@font-face { font-family: 'Palatino'; src: local('Garamond'); }`. This fixes the problem.

If I find a more satisfying solution I'll post that.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, but all over the installation. Weird numbers in Thunderbird, QT applications, ... They also have some strange padding, causing a lot of whitespace.

Comment: Hi @skerit, did the user stylesheet help at all in your case?